# How to get the response of a scrapy request

Tags: scrapy

I am making a scrapy request to get all the data of a site. I am trying to get the response of the full request, however I am not getting any result. I send the code attached. Thanks for your help.
`

```
class FilminSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'filmin'
    allowed_domains = ['filmin.es']
    start_urls = ['https://www.filmin.es/wapi/catalog/browse?type=film&page=2&limit=60']
    def get_all_movies_data(self):
        url = 'https://www.filmin.es/wapi/catalog/browse?type=film&page=2&limit=60'
        headers = {"x-requested-with": "XMLHttpRequest"}
        request = Request(url = url, method = 'GET',dont_filter = True
        ,headers = headers)
    def parse(self, response):
        return response.request
```

`

Answer (score 0):

pls have a look at this example below you may get something

```html
class ErrbackSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "errback_example"
    start_urls = [
        "http://www.httpbin.org/",              # HTTP 200 expected
        "http://www.httpbin.org/status/404",    # Not found error
        "http://www.httpbin.org/status/500",    # server issue
        "http://www.httpbin.org:12345/",        # non-responding host, timeout expected
        "http://www.httphttpbinbin.org/",       # DNS error expected
    ]

    def start_requests(self):
        for u in self.start_urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(u, callback=self.parse_httpbin,
                                    errback=self.errback_httpbin,
                                    dont_filter=True)

    def parse_httpbin(self, response):
        self.logger.info('Got successful response from {}'.format(response.url))
        # do something useful here...

    def errback_httpbin(self, failure):
        # log all failures
        self.logger.error(repr(failure))

        # in case you want to do something special for some errors,
        # you may need the failure's type:

        if failure.check(HttpError):
            # these exceptions come from HttpError spider middleware
            # you can get the non-200 response
            response = failure.value.response
            self.logger.error('HttpError on %s', response.url)

        elif failure.check(DNSLookupError):
            # this is the original request
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('DNSLookupError on %s', request.url)

        elif failure.check(TimeoutError, TCPTimedOutError):
            request = failure.request
            self.logger.error('TimeoutError on %s', request.url)
```